# How can I refer and link to other posts in my post?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

Several times, when asking a question or posting an answer, I have to rely on another question/answer (or even a comment!) somewhere in the site.
I generally do this:

> ```
> ... as mentioned in [this answer](<the url>).
> ```

for an answer, and

> ```
> ... after reading [<question title>](<the url>).
> ```

for a question.

However, earlier, I used to refer to these posts by the user's name:

> ```
> ... as mentioned by [<username>](<the url>) in their question/answer.
> ```

Which of these ways is correct / appropriate / generally followed?
Or are they all fine?
Is there a way that is *not* recommended?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All the ways to link you mentioned are considered just fine.

But more important, besides the link (formatted in which ever possible way), you should **always** cite the linked post in your question, and put the essential text you're referring to literally.

The link can be considered as a decoration more or less.

Other questions or answers may be deleted and thus become invisible for users under 10k reputation, and render your whole question or answer useless for future research.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend to always include title of the question in the reference:
For an answer

> ```
> as mentioned in [<username> answer in <question title>](<the answer url>).
> ```

Exception is when you reference to another answer of the same question

> ```
> as mentioned in [<username> answer for this question](<the answer url>).
> ```

To add reference to a question in your post it’s enough to specify `<the url>`, and site will automatically substitute `[<question title>](<the url>)`.
However in comments you need to provide title manually `[<question title>](<the url>)`.